# How to use VBS to manage LibreOffice Calc files?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, vbscript

I am learning VBS scripts and someone gave me a code below, that works with Microsoft Excel. How to convert it to work with LibreOffice Calc?

```
Dim ObjExcel 
Call ExcelSetup("Sheet1")

Sub ExcelSetup(sheetName)
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set objwb = objExcel.Workbooks.Add 
  Set objwb = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName) 

  Objwb.Name = "Sheet name for user"
  objwb.Activate 
  objExcel.Visible = True 
  objwb.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Hello world!" 
End Sub 

MsgBox "The End"
```

Comment: Did you do any research? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script, adapted from https://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/tutorial/office_automation.html:

```
Set oSM = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
Set oDesk = oSM.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
Dim arg()
Set wb = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/scalc", "_blank", 0, arg)
Set oSheet = wb.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
oSheet.getCellByPosition(1, 2).String = "Hello world!"
MsgBox "The End"
```